# Intune, Autopilot Self Deploy + Multi App Kiosk (Guest account auto login), new apps install stay as pending forever

Tags: azure, mdm, intune

I have a multi app kiosk pc working fine with intune, it was deployed using self deploy autopilot, and the machine does not have a user associated, it was configured to use auto logon and uses a guest account (Kiosk).

I need to install new apps in the pc, but new apps never install, they stay as pending install, no matter how many times I click sync on intune or I wait or I restart the pc.

**repro steps**

1. Assigned the Intune (Device) license to the group the machine is part of in Azure AD.
2. Computer gets enrolled via Autopilot Self deploy and get apps installed.
3. the pc gets the configuration profile (Multi app kiosk) , configured to use guest account only. (Which means there is no user associated )
4. We can login with the Kiosk account (no credentials needed), and can use the apps enabled in kiosks.

**The issue I am struggling with>**

Now that the machine is working a a kiosk, if I try to install a new app from intune, the app stays as pending install.

I found this forum>
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/378888/win32-apps-don39t-install-on-intune-kiosk.html

saying it was like a known issue and MS solution was to log off and stay at the windows login screen. That way after waiting a couple of hours, intune would try to install the apps using Device token (because its in login screen) and eventually the app will be installed.

I tested that, but it did not work, left the pc turned on at the login screen all night and the app is still showing as pending install.

**Any idea how to install new apps on a PC that is already setup as kiosk from Intune?**

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?